# Building a backup server

Tags: backup, cpu, motherboard, home-server

One of my older motherboards broke and I'm planning to use the remaining power supply, hard drive and case to build a backup server. I want to buy a new motherboard and CPU that can be used 24x7 and wont break down in a few months.

So the question is, do you have any recommendations on any reliable motherboards and CPU for a backup server? Processing power is not a huge issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [Atom](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=40000446&Description=atom&name=Motherboard%20%2f%20CPU%20%2f%20VGA%20Combo) motherboard/CPU combos are generally a good bet for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could even try for a low end Intel Celeron models which could be suitable for your purpose. Not sure about the exact price though.

Answer (score 0):

I've had absolutely same issue and results are described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/45497/low-power-motherboard-for-windows-home-server). Have it in mind.